# Cannot find module 'wrappy'

Tags: npm, gulp

while i tried to install **gulp** from package manager console in visual studio 2015.

**npm install gulp**

I got error **Cannot find module 'wrappy'**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do `npm update`. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Check your node version, it might be too out-of-date for the package you are trying to install.

You can do this from a command line or terminal window:

```
node -v
```

When I get the 'wrappy' error it's always because I used nvm to set node to an older version for a specific project, but then tried to install a package on a newer project that uses a modern node version.

Answer (score 0):

**Why the error comes**

This error shows up because you have installed a new npm version over an old one.

You would think that the node.js installation would remove all the npm installation folders and files from your computer but it is simply not happening!

**Solution:-**

Solve this error first uninstall Nodejs

%AppData% in the search bar of windows
[image]

or go path C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming

inside Roaming Folder look 2 folders "npm" and "npm-cache".Just delete both of them.

Restart your computer and redownload node.js ,install it
Restart again and inside command prompt

node-v and npm-v

[image]

Both commands should work now